# Git clone through process builder in java

Tags: java, git, command-prompt, processbuilder

I want to run the following command through process builder in java:

```
Git clone --depth 1 <url>
```

The requirement is to interact with command prompt to fill the username and password when asked. 
When i hit this command through cmd, it asks for username and password But when I do the same thing through process builder in java, instead of asking for username and password it gives the following error:

```
Bash: dev/tty no such command or device 
Error: couldn't get username ..
```

And the code exits.
Note: providing username and password in the url itself is not desirable. Also using window credentials msnager popup is not desirable and has been set to false.

Comment: You might find it easier to use one of the available java git libraries. It's also not clear what is 'undesirable' about construction an authenticated url, you don't have to hardcode the auth info into your program.

Comment: @pvg I was earlier using jgit library to perform all these functions but shallow clone is not available in jgit so I have to move to running the commands through process builder. Also if I give username and password in the url, it stores these 2 in .git config file so whenever password changes I have to delete the .git folder or change the config file which is not desirable.

Comment: You have a lot of control over how git uses and stores credentials, just look at git help credentials for starters. You can also change the config file through git invocations. Saner still is to simply use ssh keys.

Comment: Unfortunately, the git repo that I am trying to access doesn't support ssh